# Rails radio_button check conditionally in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, formhelper

I have radiobuttons creaated in loop.

```
- @annual_packages.each do |plan|
    = f.radio_button('plan_id', plan.id)
    = plan.title
```

How can I make condition to check radio if **plan.id == @plan.id**

Doesn't work:

```
 = f.radio_button('plan_id', plan.id, checked: (plan.id == @plan.id))
```

Loop code:

```
= form_for @organization, url: subscription_create_path, remote: true, method: :post do |f|
   - unless @annual_packages.blank?
     - @annual_packages.each do |plan|
       = f.radio_button('plan_id', plan.id)
       = plan.title
```

Comment: what you are trying to do? are you trying to show plan titles as tag to radio buttons and accept plan_id for form object? what is @plan?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your `form_for` code?

Cause if your column `plan_id` have any value, it should be checked automatically if it matches the tag_value`.

> If the current value of method is tag_value the radio button will be
>   checked.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-radio_button

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `simple_form` or `form_for`, and f is your form object then you can simply do:

for form_for:
`radio_button(object_name, method, tag_value, options = {})` [refer](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/radio_button)

in your case:

```
 - @annual_packages.each do |plan|
    radio_button("your object name", "plan_id", plan.id, options = {})
```

If the current value of method(object.plan_id) is tag_value(plan) the radio button will be checked.

for simple_form:

```
= f.input :plan_id, as: :radio_buttons, collection: @annual_packages
```